# Google Places API for iOS Quota

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api, google-console-developer

We have an iOS app which uses Google Places API for iOS. We realized upon launch that we receive more than a 100 requests in a day which is causing our app to break because we reached our limit.

Now, we've increased our limit with the help of Google and I want to know if already generated API keys will be affected or we have to generate new API keys .

Also, where can we see the quota used on the console. because what we have currently shows 0/150000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, your already generated keys should have the new limit of 150,000.

Also, for the quota, it does not update immediately, you'll have to wait a bit till they start showing up.

Comment: The quota still doesnt update. But I'll accept because this was most helpful.